# Wow js - эффекты in и out

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть `wow js` - http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Позволяет реализовать анимацию при прокрутке страницы.
Есть как `in` эффекты, так и `out` эффекты - эффекты появления и пропадания.

Как сделать так, чтобы для кнопки (допустим) был одновременно как эффект появления, при `200px` от низа `data-wow-offset` и эффект пропадания при `500рх` от низа.

Пример: http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

После `Get skills` - `Fade It` и `Fly It` Опуститесь вниз и увидите эффект, поднимитесь вверх и эффект исчезнет, как и появлялся.

Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body{
 align-items: center;
 background: #9575CD;
 color: #fff;
 display: flex;
 font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.div-1{
 align-items: center;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 width: calc(100vw - 20px);
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head> 
   <title> </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="all">
   
   <div class="div1 wow fadeOut animated"  data-wow-delay="2s">
    <div class="div-1 wow fadeIn animated">
     Hello, world! One
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>

  <script src="wow.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   new WOW().init();
   </script>
   
  </body>
 </html>
```